# Python slice and lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, slice

I have this in a for loop in Python:

"keys" is just a list of positive integers

```
e=0
for f in keys[e + 1:]:
```

Can you explain what exactly happens each cycle?
Does it mean, that each time the value of
keys[1] is added to e  ?

Answer (score 0):

since e+1 = 1, the slice "keys[e+1:]" essentially omits the first element of the list. The for loop gives you the elements of the list (except for the first) one-by-one in order, assigning each one to the variable "f". Neither the list, nor the variable "e" change in any way

Answer (score 0):

write it this way to be more clear:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
e = 0
keys2 = keys[e+1:] # this returns a second list with items [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for f in keys2:
    print f
```

if you did:

```
keys[2:]
```

returns a new list with items from position 2 until the end of keys

```
keys[1:2] -> [2]
```